# share project between solutions with tfs 2013

Tags: shared-libraries

We are starting to use TFS2013 (we use svn still, but for a number of reasons we're putting new code on TFS).

I have a solution that contains a project with an EF database model and I would like to share it with a different solution (to be more specific: there is a client website solution and a separate one for backend).

On SVN I would have created svn externals - I would be able to share the code easily and if I branched, the shared project would have a nice copy on branch as well. Moreover, both projects would have the most up-to-date version of the db model, which suits me perfectly.

TFS 2013 seems to push be pushing towards NuGets. That means, that if I create a nuget package of the db project:

- I will have to update the db projec separately each time there is a db change, release it and then update all projects that use it
- If I branch, I'll probably have to create a different nuget package for the branched version and amend the nuget reference on merge
- It pollutes the nuget repo with things that are not exactly worth a repository (in case of a DB model, you want to have the latest possible version because a website will probably break if you don't, no point for versioning so that the build doesn't break)

I spent some time trying to find a suitable solution, but the best idea I found is just referencing the project from a different solution - the problem with it is, I would have to make the root folder for the build be higher than just the solution and that would add several more projects that I don't need. Another idea is referencing by branching, which was good for TFS 2010 with multiple projects, but I can't fit it into my scenario (we have a single 'Main' node where we put all solutions).

So, how would you share a DB project on TFS 2013?

Comment: Go for NuGet packages. Sharing source code directly or indirectly by doing baseless merge makes things more complicated.

Comment: Is there a decent way to make a branch of a NuGet package? Because the only way I can think of is to edit the id of a package, edit all branched apps that use it and then change everything back to original when merging.

Comment: I suggest that each branch create different version. Your main/trunk build 0.X - then you have a 1.0 branch that create version 1.X NuGet packages, ...

Comment: That actually makes sense. People would just need to be careful which version they are using and if they are updating anything in trunk, just see to it they are not fetching the highest revision, but rather the one with the same major revision.

Thanks